# Error al crear SP en oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c, oracle-10g

Al crear mi SP en oracle me genera error, el error me lo da en la linea donde asigno a total la Query

> Total:=(Select sum(Monto_Total) as suma  from TablaC where id = Amount.id_camp);

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (19: 15): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:    
   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue
[Error] PLS-00103 (19: 76): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:    
   . , @ ; for <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect
   minus order partition sta
[Error] PLS-00103 (22: 5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following: ;
```

este es mi codigo

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Cifras AS
 Total INT;
   BEGIN
for Archivo in
(select  File from TablaA where Folio='E7777' and Tipo = 1 group by File
)
loop
for Amount in
(
select id_camp from TablaB where name =  Archivo.File
)
loop
 Total:=(Select sum(Monto_Total) as suma  from TablaC where id = Amount.id_camp);
 dbms_output.put_line('Archivo: ' || Total);
end loop;
end loop;
   END;
```

Comment: Por favor, no publiques mensajes de error en imágenes. Edita tu pregunta e incluye el texto del mensaje de error directamente.

Comment: Si hay volumen de datos, tu SP va a ser ineficiente. Debieras hacer un join entre las tablas y un solo bucle para recorrerlo. El motor probablemente encontrará una forma más eficiente de hacer el _join_ que _nested loops_. Y si fuera _nested loops_, de cualquier manera, va a ser mucho más rápido que lo haga el motor y no tu código.

Comment: @jachguate pero las querys las tengo en cascada del resultado de una uso como parametro para ejecutar la otra, como puedo hacer el join?

Comment: Dado que el _parámetro_ pasa directo de un query a otro, según veo, esa sería la condición del _join_.

Answer (score 1):

En PL/SQL, no puedes asignar a una variable el resultado de un *subquery* de la manera que lo estás haciendo, quizás vengas de SQL-Server (TSQL) u otro motor dónde si se puede.

En Oracle, lo que puedes hacer es un `select into`, así:

```
Select sum(Monto_Total) into Total from TablaC where id = Amount.id_camp;
```